# Miner bot taking up CPU on old server

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, malware, botnet

I've been asked to take a look at an old web server (Ubuntu 12.04) which has been running very slow recently.

After a quick check I found a process constantly topping the cpu:

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
26331 root      20   0  413m 1728 1188 S  400  0.0 740:47.17 Welcom
```

It was running from the /tmp directory where I found these 3 files

```
/tmp
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root         root            11624 Dec 29 14:50 tmplog
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root         root                0 Jan  9 04:12 Wel*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root         root          1659720 Jan  6 22:18 Welcom*
```

the tmplog file kinda suggested it was a cryptocurrency miner:

```
tmplog top line
CMD: /bin/wipefs -B -o stratum+tcp://pool.minexmr.com:443 -u 45WnHu.......
```

I immediately removed the files from /tmp /bin and /etc/init.d which were linked to these executables, stopped the process and disabled root ssh login.

A minute or so later the Welcom file was back in /tmp and the process was up and running again.

I did some research and found these:

https://f5.com/labs/articles/threat-intelligence/malware/new-python-based-crypto-miner-botnet-flying-under-the-radar

https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/4d289aac77e0e2e7b8d109dd1fa4f6ac2079d64d98e97ce0b6c24462c228547e?environmentId=300

But I only managed to locate the templog wipefs from the list of files. The templog is no longer updated but the Welcom executable gets recreated in both /tmp and /bin

How can I get rid of this without thrashing the box? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: *How can I get rid of this without thrashing the box?* -- Restore known good backups to a supported version of the OS.

Comment: its a physical server, but never mind i get the sentiment

Comment: Why do you not want to "trash" the box? It's an Ubuntu 12.04, it's been End of Life for eight months already (unless you're and Ubuntu Advantage customer, which will get you security updates only). It should take you less time to reinstall than to clean up.